# Сравнение введенных данных с уже существующими

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день, подскажите в какую сторону копать!

Есть база данных `"infos"`, в ней таблица `"u_info"`, первая колонка содержит имя пользователя и называется `"uname"`, так вот необходимо что бы при выполнения функции `showInfo`, проводилась проверка, если такое имя уже используется то вернуть `echo "Это имя/email уже занято"`, не допру как правильно вытащить массив чтобы сравнить, массив существует как я понял тока пределах `while`, данные для сравнения поступают из `$_POST['name']`.

```
function showInfo () {
  // Соединение с сервером БД
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());

  // Выбор БД
  mysql_select_db("infos") or die(mysql_error());

  // SQL-запрос

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT uname FROM u_info");
  $form_name = $_POST['name'];

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        if(in_array($form_name, $row)){
            echo "Это имя/email уже занято";
            exit; 
        }else{
             echo "Допустимое значение";
             someFunct();
        };
    };

    // Закрыть соединение с БД
    mysql_close();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте про конструкцию `WHERE` в `SQL`.

Comment: Сейчас скрипт получает все записи таблицы.
А достаточно сделать проверку на наличие данного значения в этой таблице:

SELECT uname FROM u_info WHERE uname = '". mysql_real_escape_string($name) ."'"

Comment: Спасибо! Не совсем понял вот тут SELECT uname FROM u_info WHERE uname = '". mysql_real_escape_string($name) ."'" ! Но буду  "курить" маны и пробовать! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо! Решил вот так вот!

```
// SQL-запрос

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT uname FROM u_info");

  $res = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
  $res[] = $row[0];
  if (in_array($form_name,$res)){
      echo "found this shit";
  } else{

echo "Your shit not Found";
  };

    // Закрыть соединение с БД
    mysql_close();
};
```

Comment: вот ещё проще
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT uname FROM u_info WHERE id = '1'");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql)){
 // ЕСТЬ
} else {
 // НЕТУ
}

Comment: Вот так заработало! 

        $nameF =$_POST['name'];
        $nQ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name ='$nameF'");

       if(mysql_num_rows($nQ)) {
    
       echo "name found";
       }
        else {
          echo"name NOT found";

        };

        mysql_close();